# Async write file million times cause out of memory

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Below is code:

```
var fs = require('fs')

for(let i=0;i<6551200;i++){
    fs.appendFile('file',i,function(err){

    })
}
```

When I run this code, after a few seconds, it show:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

and yet nothing in file!

my qusetion is :

1. why is no byte in file?
2. where cause out of memory?
3. how to async write file in for loop no mater how large the write times?

thanks advance.

Comment: What happens if you process that sequentially in batch of 10? For example, you write i = 0...10 to file and once that's done, you do the next ten etc. You can use something like [async.times](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times)

Comment: What if you wrap the loop body in an iife? `for(...) { (function(i) { ... })(i) }` As each iife exits, its memory uage should be collected

Comment: @tsuz thank you, I have tried async.times.but it doesn't work and crash.

Comment: @JoeFrambach thanks however when I run your code it will also cause out of memory problem. I think even if you wrap the fs.apendFile function in for loop but it is not going to wait callback finish so as to it will  calloc memory until it drain

Comment: @suoyong that's because you're running the next async.times in the loop without waiting for the previous one to finish. The point is to control the flow, processing parts at a time.

Comment: @suoyong Also, you're opening the file descriptor every time in the loop. You should move fs.appendFile out of the loop and write chunks at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line here is that `fs.appendFile()` is an asynchronous call and you simply are not "awaiting" that call to complete on each loop iteration. This has a number of consequences, including but not limited to:

- The callbacks keep getting allocated before they are resolved, which results in the ***"heap out of memory"*** eventually being reached.
- You are contesting with a file handle, since you the function you are employing is actually opening/writing/closing the file given, and if you don't wait for each turn to do so, then you're simply going to clash.

So the simple solution here is to ***"wait"***, and some modern syntax sugar makes that easy:

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');

const x = 6551200;

(async function() {
  try {
    const fd = await fs.open('file','w');
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      await fs.write(fd, `${i}\n`);
    }
    await fs.close(fd);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit();
  }
})()
```

That will of course take a while, but it's not going to "blow up" your system whilst it does it's work.

The very first simplified thing is to just get hold of the [`mz`](https://github.com/normalize/mz) library, which already wraps common nodejs libraries with modernized versions of each function supporting promises. This will help clean up the syntax a lot as opposed to using callbacks.

The next thing to realize is what was mentioned about that `fs.appendFile()` in how it is "opening/writing/closing" all in one call. That's not great, so what you would typically do is simply `open` and then `write` the bytes in a loop, and when that is complete you can actually `close` the file handle.

That "sugar" comes in modern versions, and though *"possible"* with plain promise chaining, it's still not really that manageable. So if you don't actually have a nodejs environment that supports that `async/await` sugar or the tools to "transpile" such code, then you might alternately consider using the [`asyncjs`](http://caolan.github.io/async/) libary with plain callbacks:

```
const Async = require('async');
const fs = require('fs');

const x = 6551200;

let i = 0;
fs.open('file','w',(err,fd) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  Async.whilst(
    () => i < x,
    callback => fs.write(fd,`${i}\n`,err => {
      i++;
      callback(err)
    }),
    err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      fs.closeSync(fd);
      process.exit();
    }
  );

});
```

The same base principle applies as we are "waiting" for each callback to complete before continuing. the [`whilst()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst) helper here allows iteration until the test condition is met, and of course does not do the next iteration until data is passed to the callback of the iterator itself.

There are other ways to approach this, but those are probably the two most sane for a "large loop" of iterations. Common approaches such as "chaining" via `.reduce()` are really more suited to a "reasonable" sized array of data you already have, and building arrays of such sizes here has inherent problems of it's own.

For instance, the following *"works"* ( on my machine at least ) but it really consumes a lot of resources to do it:

```
const fs = require('mz/fs');
const x = 6551200;

fs.open('file','w')
  .then( fd =>
    [ ...Array(x)].reduce(
      (p,e,i) => p.then( () => fs.write(fd,`${i}\n`) )
      , Promise.resolve()
    )
    .then(() => fs.close(fd))
  )
  .catch(e => console.error(e) )
  .then(() => process.exit());
```

So that's really not that practical to essentially build such a large chain in memory and then allow it to resolve. You could put some *"governance"* on this, but the main two approaches as shown are a lot more straightforward.

For that case then you either have the `async/await` sugar available as it is within current LTS versions of Node ( LTS 8.x ), or I would stick with the other tried and true "async helpers" for callbacks where you were restricted to a version without that support

---

You can of course "promisify" any function with the last few releases of nodejs right "out of the box" as it where, as `Promise` has been a global thing for some time:

```
const fs = require('fs');

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => fs.open('file','w',(err,fd) => {
  if (err) reject(err);
  resolve(fd);
});
```

So there really is no need to import libraries just to do that, but the [`mz`](https://github.com/normalize/mz) library given as example here does all of that for you. So it's really up to personal preferences on bringing in additional dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Neil Lunn .That solved my problem, precious tip.

Answer (score 0):

1 - The file is empty because none of the fs.append calls have ever finished, the Node.JS process broken before.

2 - The Node.JS heap memory is limited and stores the callback until it returns, not only the "i" variable.

3 - You could try to use promises to do that.

```
"use strict";

const Bluebird = require('bluebird');
const fs = Bluebird.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

let promisses = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 6551200; i++){
    promisses.push(fs.appendFileAsync('file', i + '\n'));
}

Bluebird.all(promisses)
.then(data => {
  console.log(data, 'End.');
})
.catch(e => console.error(e));
```

But no logic can avoid heap memory error for a loop this big. You could increase Node.JS Heep Memory or, the reasonable way, take chunks of data for interval:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let total = 6551200;

let interval = setInterval(() => {
  fs.appendFile('file', total + '\n', () => {});
  total--;
  if (total < 1) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 1);
```

Comment: This just creates an array of 6.5 million elements and `Bluebird.all` does not guarantee that it runs sequentially (possibly in parallel). The second one assumes `fs.appendFile` completes writing within 1ms.

Comment: Thanks the reply, bluebird is fantastic module, it can not loop million times nevertheless.the setInterval is a good work around. But how to guarantee the task finish in setInterval callback e.g.  fs.apendFile, socket.send...  thanks again.

Comment: This is a simple example, you could use a recursive approach, like function x() { fs.appendAsync().then(() => x()).catch(e => console.log(e)); I use this interval approach in production in several micro services that parse files, usually the interval is bigger than 1 ms, nonetheless it gt the work done.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a single threaded language, which means your code can execute one function at the time. So when you execute an async function, it will be "queued" in the stack to be executed next.

so in your code, you are sending 6551200 calls to the stack, which would of course crash your app before starting working "appendFile" on any of them.

you can achieve what you want by splitting your loop into smaller loops, use async and await functions, or iterators.

if what you are trying to achieve is as simple as your code, you can use the following:

```
const fs = require("fs");

function SomeTask(i=0){
    fs.appendFile('file',i,function(err){
        //err in the write function
        if(err) console.log("Error", err);
        //check if you want to continue (loop)
        if(i<6551200) return SomeTask(i);
        //on finish
        console.log("done");
    });
}
SomeTask();
```

In the above code, you write a single line, and when that is done, you call the next one.
This function is just for basic usage, it needs a refactor and use of Javascript Iterators for advanced usage [check out Iterators and generators on MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)

Comment: Thanks for the constructive iterator answer. if I iterate million time the memory also exhaust, doesn't it?