# puppeteer only scraping around 200 pages and don't continue

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodes, puppeteer

for some reason that I don't understand my node app stops scraping after few minutes without any errors while only scraping, btw its an infinity scroll website...
this is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

(async() => {
    // start the browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
    // open a new page
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const pageURL = 'http://www.yad4.co.il/dogs//////////////#1';
    try {
        // try to go to URL
        await page.goto(pageURL);
        console.log(`opened the page: ${pageURL}`);
        await page.setViewport({
            width: 1200,
            height: 800
        });
        await autoScroll(page);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`failed to open the page: ${pageURL} with the error: ${error}`);
    }
  // Find all links to dogs
  const postsSelector = '.yd-search-page .container .row .col-md-9 .yd-gallery .search-handler-yd .col-xs-12 #dogs_more .col-md-4 .yd-dog-img .yd-mask a';
  await page.waitForSelector(postsSelector);
  const postUrls = await page.$$eval(postsSelector, postLinks => postLinks.map(link => link.href));

  // Visit each page one by one
  for (let postUrl of postUrls) {

      // open the page
      try {
          await page.goto(postUrl);
          console.log('opened the page: ', postUrl);
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log('failed to open the page: ', postUrl);
      }
      // get the name of the dog
      const dogSelector = '.adopt.yd-amuta .container .yd-dog-cont .col-xs-12 .adopt-head .row .col-sm-6 .adopt-breadcrumb-title h2 span';
     // await page.waitForSelector(dogSelector);
      const dogName = await page.$eval(dogSelector, dogSelector => dogSelector.innerHTML);

        // Writing the news inside a json file
 fs.appendFile("dogtest4.json", JSON.stringify({dogName},), function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Saved!");
  });

    }
    // all done, close the browser
    await browser.close();

    async function autoScroll(page){
        await page.evaluate(async () => {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var totalHeight = 0;
                var distance = 100;
                var timer = setInterval(() => {
                    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                    window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                    totalHeight += distance;
    
                    if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        resolve();
                    }
                }, 100);
            });
         
        });
    }    
    process.exit()
})();
```

so it gives me information but randomly, I mean sometimes it gives me 115 pages sometimes 300 pages and some times barely 90 pages and I don't understand why,
please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: what's the browser's timeout? set timeout to 0 in the launch option and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: also add some time between scrolls, for 3-5 seconds, you could be blocked by the site for malicious activity

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but I suppose it could be something to do with memory limit being reached and that slows things down.

you can try adding "await" in front of fs.appendFile(...) [like here explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952037/async-write-file-million-times-cause-out-of-memory), might work for you